# How do I deal with "Project Files" in my Qt application?

Tags: c++, xml, qt, settings

My Qt application should be able to create/open/save a single "Project" at once. What is the painless way to store project's settings in a file? Should it be XML or something less horrible?

Of course data to be stored in a file is a subject to change over time.

What I need is something like `QSettings` but bounded to a **project** in my application rather than to the whole application.

Comment: What do you mean by projcet settings? Doesn't the Qt generated project/Makefile suffice?

Comment: what  he means: his program uses different projects. He wants to know the best way to save this.

Comment: @PoweRoy, that's what I do want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use QSettings to store data in a specific .ini file. 
From the docs:

Sometimes you do want to access settings stored in a specific file or registry path. On all platforms, if you want to read an INI file directly, you can use the QSettings constructor that takes a file name as first argument and pass QSettings::IniFormat as second argument. For example:
 QSettings settings("/home/petra/misc/myapp.ini",
                    QSettings::IniFormat);

Answer (score 1):

I order to make it user editable, I would stick to plain text with one key = values by line, like in most of the Linux apps.

However this is only for the settings, not for the complete project's data which I suppose requires more complex structures.

So maybe [JSON](http://www.json.org/) ?

Answer (score 1):

Pro XML:

- You can have a look at it in an editor
- You can store any kind of string in any language in it (unicode support)
- It's simple to learn
- More than one program can read the same XML
- It's easy to structure your data with XML. When you use key/value lists, for example, you'll run into problems when you need to save tree-like structures.

Contra XML

- The result is somewhat bloated
- Most programming languages (especially old ones like C++) have no good support for XML. The old XML APIs were designed in such a way that they could be implemented in any language (smallest common denominator). 'nuff said.
- You need to understand the concept of "encoding" (or "charset"). While this may look trivial at first glance, there are some hidden issues which can bite you. So always test your code with some umlauts and even kanji (Japanese characters) to make sure you got it right.

Comment: This API is based on DOM which, in my book, is not a "very good XML API". I prefer thinks like "html.body.p[3].text = '...'" instead of getRootElement().getChildElement("body").getChildElements("p").get(3).setText("...");